# Use a custom Laravel Dusk selector attribute (data-dusk)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-dusk

The default Laravel Dusk selector looks for the `dusk="something"` attribute in your HTML.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/dusk#dusk-selectors

This is not very compatible when using Typescript for React/Vue as it is not a standard HTML element attribute.

It would be more compatible to use an attribute such as `data-dusk="something"` as Typescript knows anything prefixed with `data-` is a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but you can change the the attribute that Dusk looks for by adding this to the `boot()` method of your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...

        \Laravel\Dusk\Dusk::selectorHtmlAttribute('data-dusk');
    }
}
```

Taylor added this in this commit: https://github.com/laravel/dusk/commit/cf04717664f80204567ad3077ea7484a0be16497